# Angular Authentication HttpCookie || Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, angular, authentication, cookies

`withcredentials="true"` is not sending the cookie in the get request to API project.

Added API and Angular solution with this section of code  .

Tried added the cookie in the Response Object and Getting the cookies in next request.

I'm trying to implement the HTTPonly Cookies Authentication with Angular

```
public HttpResponseMessage Authenticate(User user)
{
        var httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();

        JWTService _jwtService = new JWTService();
        var authencatedUser = userList.FirstOrDefault(p => p.UserName == user.UserName && p.Password == user.Password);

        if (authencatedUser != null && authencatedUser.Id > 0)
        {
            AuthenticateDto authenticateDto = new AuthenticateDto()
            {
                AccessToken = _jwtService.GenerateAccessToken(authencatedUser, Request.Headers.Referrer != null ? Request.Headers.Referrer.Authority : ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Audiences"].Split(',').ToList().FirstOrDefault()),
                FirstName = authencatedUser.FirstName,
                Username = authencatedUser.UserName
            };

            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("XSRF-TOKEN");

            cookie["XSRF-TOKEN"] = authenticateDto.AccessToken;

            cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
            //cookie.Domain = Request.RequestUri.Host;
            cookie.Secure = true;

            httpResponseMessage = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { status = true, data = authenticateDto, message = "Success" });
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            return httpResponseMessage;
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, new { message = "User not found" });
        }
}
```

```
export class HeaderIterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private authService : AuthService, private baseService: BaseService,private router : Router
  ) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

debugger
    var userToken = this.baseService.getAccessToken();
    let httpHeaders: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': "bearer " + userToken })
      .append('Accept', 'application/json').append('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      .append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      let modifiedReq = request.clone({ 
        headers: httpHeaders,withCredentials: true
      });
     
     return next.handle(modifiedReq);

}
```